# How to create a sphere with an outer layer of removable pieces?

Tags: objects, normals

I'm creating a video game which requires an inner sphere ("the core") and an outer sphere. The core is a solid icosphere, but the outer core must be made of individual triangular prisms that fit tightly to the core and each other. During the course of gameplay, the pieces of the outer core are removed one by one until the core is revealed.

After making my core, I tried to make a single triangular prism piece and to use it to construct my outer sphere, but I can't get the pieces to fit together right (see below).

[image: enter description here]

I came to realize that the triangles are not all the same, so I've gone back to blender and extruded and then push/pulled all of my vertices to start an outer layer.

[image]

My question is: how can I easily connect all of these dots, create faces for each individual triangular prism (such that the normals are facing outward for each individual prism), and break them apart into individual objects so that I can save an outer sphere and import it into my game? And how can I do this with as little headache as possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your icosphere, duplicate it with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, select one of the two, go in *Edit* mode, select all and split the faces (*Mesh > Split > Faces by Edges*):

[image]

Then extrude with <kbd>E</kbd>, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> right away, and scale up with *Transform Pivot Point > Median Point* selected:

[image]

Now you have your two objects, the core and the outer sphere. You can separate each piece of the outer sphere with <kbd>P</kbd> > *By Loose Parts*:

[image]

Each of these separate pieces will have the same origin, which I guess will help to position them correctly in the 3D space of your game.

Comment: Are you somehow managing to create an extrusion along the pre-split (interpolated) vertex normals? Without that, I can't achieve solid tiles without mutual intersections (inward) or separation (outward). It would be lovely to be able to extrude/solidify along custom normals. Then you could use, say, a Data Transfer, to get the tiles to extrude along the normals as they were when the icosphere was intact. (This has come up on Right-Click-Select..)

Comment: hello, not sure about your question, I'm going to edit because actually you don't even need to scale down, actually you create your icosphere, duplicate it, split the faces, extrude and do a basic scale up, and the edges won't overlap

Comment: No big thing.. your edit has done it.

Comment: yes actually you just need to scale with Median Point activated and the edges won't overlap

Comment: I've tried following this process and haven't quite gotten it. First, I was getting stuck at the extrusion step, so I went back and split "faces and edges by vertices" which seemed to give me what I wanted, but then when I separated the selection I'm expecting to get 360+ objects, and instead I have three.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in my last picture, you need to separate "by loose parts", the rest of the steps should be correct, i've just verified